# how to find a record that don't have a dated record

Tags: sql

i've a order table where in date field stores 0 and date for the order. i need to find a order that doesn't have a date record. please see my below example, i'm only expecting the last two order, CAUT001 AND CAT002

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you can use aggregations:

```
select order
from t
group by order
having max(date) = 0;
```

If you have a separate table of `orders`, then `not exists` is also feasible:

```
select o.*
from orders o
where not exists (select 1 from t where t.order = o.order and t.date > 0);
```

(And needless to say, `order` is a bad name for anything in SQL because it is a SQL keyword.)

Comment: thank you so much, it is just a sample, i should've thought about it. My bad. i really appreciate your help.